# Docker Save through Jenkins Pipeline (+ other commands)

Tags: docker, jenkins

I see that there is some documentation on using Docker through Jenkins Pipelines here:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/

They have an example for building a Docker image:

```
node {
    checkout scm

    def customImage = docker.build("my-image:${env.BUILD_ID}")

    customImage.inside {
        sh 'make test'
    }
}
```

But I was unable to find the complete list (with examples) of Docker commands supported.
Here's some places I've looked:

- https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-workflow/
- https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin/
- https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/plugins/docker-workflow

What I was looking to do is `docker save`. Does anyone know if something like this is supported, or where it might be documented:

```
// Tar ball or filename+path
def imageTar = docker.save("${ImageFileName}.tar", "${ProjectImage}:${ProjectRelease}")
```

Comment: Normally you'd want to `docker push` the built image to a registry; [Using Docker with Pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#building-containers) describes the Groovy syntax to do that.  What would you do with a tar file once you had it?

Comment: The tarball is required for a custom local (on Jenkins) security scan.

Comment: @NeilP. Go to one of your pipeline jobs, on the left menu click on the **Pipeline Syntax** link, then on the left menu select **Global Variable Reference**, search for **docker** and you will see all available options.

Comment: @NoamHelmer comment is correct answer for how to view documentation for global variable methods in a JP shared library or plugin.

Comment: @NoamHelmer thanks - this confirms that `save` is not a supported command. If you post the same as an answer, I will mark it as the correct/accepted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands under the `docker` keyword are made available by the [Docker Pipeline Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-workflow/) which is usually installed by default with Jenkins. The full documentation of the plugin is available [Here](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/plugins/docker-workflow).

In addition because this plugin adds methods as global variables (which are available in Pipeline directly, not as steps) you can see the available options, which are based on the version of the plugin you have installed, in the **Global Variable Reference** documentation within your Jenkins instance. There are two ways to reach it:

- Navigate to:  **[JENKINS_URL]/pipeline-syntax/globals**
- Go to one of your pipeline jobs, on the left menu click on the **Pipeline Syntax** link, then on the left menu select **Global Variable Reference**

Search for the **docker** section and you will see all available options.

Back to your original question - it seems that this plugin currently does not support the *save* command. it only supports *tag*, *push*, *pull* and *run* (of all kinds).
If you find it useful you can open a feature request in the plugin's [Report an issue (Jira)](https://www.jenkins.io/participate/report-issue/redirect/#20625) page asking that they add this new capability.